# how to play alarm music in iphone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uilocalnotification

Hi I'm working with alarm application, and setting `LocalNotifications` with alarm music something like ringtone. I playing ringtone perfectly. But the problem is after clicking the "Ok" button in AlertView, ringtone is playing. How can I play immediate to receive `LocalNotification`.

I am using following code to play ringtone :

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application 
didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification 

{

      application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

      NSString *reminderText = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:kRemindMeNotificationDataKey];

      NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Mitwa.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

      NSError *error;
      player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
      player.numberOfLoops = -1;

      if (player == nil)
        NSLog([error description]);
      else
        [player play];

      [viewController showReminder:@"Good Evening Mahesh!"];

  }
```

Please, help me to play alarm after receiving Notification.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `UILocalNotification` we can set alarm and for that `UILocalNotification`  you can set sound   but that sound should be only 30 Seconds.You cant play sound which is more than 30 Seconds for local notifications. If you want song after click on alert we can play song in your app.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that you can only set the [`soundName`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009565-CH1-SW8) on [`UILocalNotification`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

As state in the documentation:

> For this property, specify the filename (including extension) of a sound resource in the application’s main bundle or UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName to request the default system sound. When the system displays an alert for a local notification or badges an application icon, it plays this sound. The default value is nil (no sound). Sounds that last longer than 30 seconds are not supported. If you specify a file with a sound that plays over 30 seconds, the default sound is played instead.

Also the file has to be in the App bundle, thus it must be there when you build your app.

Answer (score 0):

First include the `.mp3` files or `wav` into your xcode project or resources then in the method where you declare alarm settings, use `UILocalNotification`.

```
UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotif.soundName = yourSoundName;
```

Comment: @Augustine93.. Thank u very much. Could you please tell me "how to open the app "AUTOMATICALLY" when any notification come"? is it possible to open automatically?